# Python - Different recursive result if append to list or add to the list

Tags: python, list, recursion

The code below brute force creates a graph of cities and then runs it through a DFS to find the shortest path. The result I get is different whether I use 'visited.append(node)' or 'visited=visited + [node]'.  Appending to the list is incorrect does not find the shortest path.

The print within the DFS is to debug why there is a difference, but I cannot determine what the difference is.  Can anyone explain this detail to me?  Thanks!

```
def CreateGraph(cities):
  g={}
  for city in cities:
    g[city]=[]
  return g

def AddRouteToGraph(g,src,dest):
  if src in g and dest in g:
    g[src].append(dest)
  else:
    raise ValueError

cities=['Bmore', 'DC', 'SanFran', 'Philly', 'Seattle', 'NYC']
g=CreateGraph(cities)
AddRouteToGraph(g,'Bmore','Seattle')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'Bmore','Philly')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'Philly','NYC')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'DC','NYC')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'SanFran','Philly')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'SanFran','DC')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'SanFran','Seattle')
AddRouteToGraph(g,'Seattle','DC')
 
def DFS_shortest(g,node,dest,visited,shortest):
  visited.append(node)
  #visited=visited + [node]
  print(f'visited={visited} of type {type(visited)}')
  if node==dest:
    return visited
  for city in g[node]:
    if city not in visited:
      if shortest!=None:
        print(city, str(len(visited)), str(len(shortest)))
      else:
        print(city, str(len(visited)), 'None')
      if shortest==None or len(visited)<len(shortest):
        newPath=DFS_shortest(g,city,dest,visited,shortest)
        if newPath!=None:
          shortest=newPath
  return shortest

print(DFS_shortest(g,'Bmore','NYC',[],None))
```

Answer (score 3):

By doing `visited = visited + ...` you are creating a new instance of the list which is independent from the one at the previous level of recursion.

When you use `visited.append(...)` you are modifying the same object instance so, when you pass it down the recursion, the alterations at the lower levels actually modify your list at the higher level

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you pass the `visited` list to the other methods a reference is passed, so any changes (e.g append) made in those methods will affect the original `visited` list.

However, when you use `visited = visited + [node]` a new list is created and that is passed to the other methods.

E.g consider

```
def func(l):
    # l.append(1)

    l = l + [1]
    if len(l) < 10:
        func(l)

l = []
func(l)
print(l)
```

Try it out, you'll understand it once you see it.

- Using `l.append(1)`

Output,

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The original list `l`  **has** changed.

- Using `l = l + [1]`

Output,

```
[]
```

The original list `l`  **hasn't** changed.

Comment: Alain and CaptainDaVinci - thank you for your quick and complete responses.  Very helpful!